# Geofinder plugin - no longer works on EE2.8.1

Tags: cartthrob, geofinder

I have a fresh install of EE2.8.1

I want to use the Geofinder plugin and do a location search. On my result page, I am getting serious errors.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Template::assign_relationship_data() in /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/third_party/geofinder/mod.geofinder.php 
Call Stack: 0.0000 644616 1. {main}() /vagrant/xxx.dev/index.php:0 0.0023 648744
 2. require_once('/vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php') /vagrant/xxx.dev/index.php:188 0.1334 2785712 
 3. call_user_func_array() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:319 0.1334 2785848 
 4. EE->index() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:0 0.1334 2785928 
 5. EE_Core->generate_page() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/controllers/ee.php:68 0.1346 2966928 
 6. EE_Template->run_template_engine() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php:703 0.1363 2994440 7. EE_Template->fetch_and_parse() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php:157 0.1534 3191400 
 8. EE_Template->parse() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php:209 0.1542 3199400 
 9. EE_Template->tags() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php:466 0.1621 3217496 
 10. EE_Template->process_tags() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php:1178 0.1707 4095136
 11. Geofinder->location_results() /vagrant/xxx.dev/system99/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php:1559
```

Have anyone went around it

Thanks

[Developer - Rob](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/617/rob-sanchez)

Answer (score 3):

I have gotten this to work with a little massaging. I am trying to contact big robot and send them the patch currently. But you can change the plugin in two places to get it working.

In the mod.geofinder.php file around line 169 you can change

```
$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->assign_relationship_data($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
$this->EE->TMPL->var_single = array_merge($this->EE->TMPL->var_single, $this->EE->TMPL->related_markers);
```

to

```
if (version_compare(APP_VER, '2.6.0', '<')) {
    $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->assign_relationship_data($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
    $this->EE->TMPL->var_single = array_merge($this->EE->TMPL->var_single, $this->EE->TMPL->related_markers);
}
```

and you need to change the function render_with_page_fix($channel, $limit, $offset) to a completely different function

```
function render_with_page_fix($channel, $limit, $offset) {
        if ($channel->enable['pagination'] == TRUE)
        {

            if (version_compare(APP_VER, '2.8', '>=')) {
        $this->EE->load->library('pagination');
        $pagination = $this->EE->pagination->create();
        $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = $pagination->prepare($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
        $total_items = $channel->total_rows;
        $per_page = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('limit');
        $pagination->build($total_items, $per_page);
        if ($pagination->paginate === TRUE)
        {
          $pagination->build($total_items, $per_page);
        }

        return $pagination->render($channel->return_data);
      } else {
                $channel->pagination->EE->pagination->total_rows = $channel->total_rows;
                $channel->pagination->get_template();
                $channel->return_data = preg_replace(
                    "/".LD."paginate".RD.".+?".LD.'\/'."paginate".RD."/s",
                    "",
                    $channel->return_data
                );
                $channel->pagination->build($channel->total_pages);

                $config = array();
                $config['first_url']    = rtrim($channel->pagination->basepath, '/');
                $config['base_url']     = $channel->pagination->basepath;
                $config['prefix']       = 'P';
                $config['total_rows']   = $channel->total_rows;
                $config['per_page'] = $limit;
                // cur_page uses the offset because P45 (or similar) is a page
                $config['cur_page'] = $offset;
                $config['first_link']   = lang('pag_first_link');
                $config['last_link']    = lang('pag_last_link');
                $config['uri_segment']  = 0; // Allows $config['cur_page'] to override

                $channel->pagination->EE->pagination->initialize($config);
                $channel->pagination->page_links = $channel->pagination->EE->pagination->create_links();
                $channel->pagination->EE->pagination->initialize($config); // Re-initialize to reset config
                $channel->pagination->page_array = $channel->pagination->EE->pagination->create_link_array();

                $channel->pagination->current_page = floor(($offset / $limit) + 1);
                $channel->pagination->total_pages = $channel->total_pages;

                return $channel->pagination->render($channel->return_data);
            }
        } else {
            return $channel->return_data;
        }
    }
```

That should get it working.

Cory

Comment: Thanks Cory - upgrading a site to 2.8.1 now and it's having loads of issues with Fieldtypes & Module upgrades. This has sorted the Geofinder errors!